# Regex substitutes each digit individually instead of the entire number

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this url that I want to replace the id with:

```
/api/users/123456/count_pending_messages
```

If I just do this, it will replace ID for each digit:

```
url.gsub(/[\d]/, 'ID')
```

Ruby has this `o` flag. So naturally I tried appending it like so:

```
url.gsub(/[\d]/o, 'ID')
```

But it still replaces for each digit, whereas I want to replace the entire number (i.e. `123456`). What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to replace `123456` you should be trying `/\d+/`.

**+** is the quantifier which says one or more digits.

What you are doing is matching each digit **one by one**. So `ID` is replaced six times.

You need to match whole `number` by using `/\d+/`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `sub` method, and you should change your regex.

```
match = /
   (?<=\/users\/)  
   \d+              
/x

url.sub match, 'ID'
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to replace 123456(which is a resource) to ID you have to use

```
url.gsub(/\/\d+\//, '/ID/')
```

it will only replace those digits which are the part of resource to ID.